# How to implement "where" clause in linq

Tags: c#, linq

May query needs to identify id or I should say group of ids in a collection, may query is like this

```
var logs = from record in RecordCollection(string.Concat(sourcePath + fileName))
                           where record.Id == 800 && record.Id == 307 && record.Id == 314 && record.Id == 372 && record.Id == 105
                           select record;
```

is this the right way? I'm not getting any result even if there are ids in the collection. TIA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace `&&` with `||`

```
var logs = from record in RecordCollection(string.Concat(sourcePath + fileName))
           where record.Id == 800 ||
                 record.Id == 307 || 
                 record.Id == 314 || 
                 record.Id == 372 ||
                 record.Id == 105
           select record;
```

Or shorter like this:

```
var ids = new []{800,307,314,372,105};
var logs = from record in RecordCollection(string.Concat(sourcePath + fileName))
           where ids.Contains(record.Id)
           select record;
```

Comment: Thanks, i've taken the shorter one.

Comment: @KGSosa yes, that's better and also remember to accept the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want the `||` (OR) operator:

```
var logs = from record in RecordCollection(string.Concat(sourcePath + fileName))
           where record.Id == 800 || 
                 record.Id == 307 || 
                 record.Id == 314 || 
                 record.Id == 372 || 
                 record.Id == 105
           select record;
```

Right now you're checking if the one record you're currently iterating its `Id` has the value 800 and 307 and 314 and etc. You want to check if it has any of those.

Comment: Yes, I want to check those ids if there are in the list

Comment: @KGSosa what are you waiting for? A better answer?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following Code...

```
var logs = from record in RecordCollection(string.Concat(sourcePath + fileName))
                       where new List<int> { 800, 307, 314, 372, 105}.Contains(record.Id)
                       select record;
```

Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Replace `&&` with `||`.

For use in many place you should build a method. Example here :

```
public static bool IsIn<T>(this T source, params T[] values)
{
    return values.Contains(source);
}
```

and call it :

```
var logs = from record in RecordCollection(string.Concat(sourcePath + fileName))
                       where record.IsIn(800,105,307)
                       select record;
```